# Putting home location and name in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I want to put my home address in Google Maps forever.

I registered my home location like a shopping mall, Restaurant, bar, hotels, shops store, office etc.

Please describe step by step.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  At the moment your question does not say precisely the steps you performed to try to do this and the outcome that you observed.  Asking for "step by step" instructions usually results in questions that are too broad for our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question makes no sense or is unclear.
You do not state why you want to put your home adress/ name in Google Maps. Don't think that there is a attribute for "Home of sudip mondal".

Google Maps are not the yellow pages. Only "relevant" information like businesses, doctors etc. are shown there.

If you have a business use the Google Maps Map Maker, if it´s - so I understood you - your private adress, there is no use for it on Google Maps. The inspectors of Google Maps will delete it everytime they found it.